# C++/SFML Graphing Application-Repeating Texture/Sprite

Tags: c++, textures, sprite, sfml, repeat

I was taking up the challenge of creating a program to use for graphing simple math equations using C++ and the SFML 2.3.2. graphics library, and I've got the graph paper texture rendering fine.  However, the problem I've had is getting it to repeat itself as I scroll around.

I was using sf::View to get it to pan, and it works well, but as soon as it pans outside the pre-defined size of the sprite it's just a blank background.

I thought of trying to determine when I'm outside the bounds of the sprite, and then expanding the size of the sprite or moving it, but then drawings (such as a graph) won't persist if the sprite is changed/reset.

What I need to know is how to create a background of a texture, in this case graphing paper, that will tile/repeat in every direction, and allow drawings to be made on top of it that persist if they move off screen.

Code is below:

GraphPaper.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"

class GraphPaper
{
    public:
        GraphPaper();
        ~GraphPaper();
        bool isObjectLoaded();
        sf::Sprite getSprite();

    private:
        void load(std::string filename);
        bool isLoaded;

        sf::Texture texture;
        sf::Sprite sprite;

        const std::string file = "images/Graph-Paper.png";
};
```

GraphPaper.cpp:  This is where I create and load the needed sprite and texture.
I set the texture to repeat inside the "load(string filename)" method, but that only affects it within the bounds set by the sprite's rectangle.

```
#include "GraphPaper.h"

GraphPaper::GraphPaper() : isLoaded(false)
{
    load(file);
    assert(isObjectLoaded());
}
GraphPaper::~GraphPaper() {};

void GraphPaper::load(std::string filename)
{
    if (texture.loadFromFile(filename) == false)
        isLoaded = false;
    else
    {
        texture.setRepeated(true);
        sprite.setTexture(texture);
        //Huge size to at least make it look like it's infinite, 
        //but a temporary solution.
        sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0,0,10000,10000));
        isLoaded = true;
    }
}
bool GraphPaper::isObjectLoaded()
{
    return isLoaded;
}
sf::Sprite GraphPaper::getSprite()
{
    return sprite;
}
```

MainWindow.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "GraphPaper.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

class MainWindow
{
    public:
         void close();
         void start();
         void moveCamera(sf::Event);

    private:
        bool leftMousePressed, rightMousePressed, isExiting;
        int r, g, b, mouseX, mouseY;

        GraphPaper paper;

        const sf::Color white = sf::Color(255, 255, 255);

        sf::RenderWindow mainWindow;
        sf::View view;
};
```

MainWindow.cpp:  This is what handles all the drawing, and, at the moment, all input processing.  "start()" is simply called from the main method.

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "GraphPaper.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

void MainWindow::start()
{
    sf::RectangleShape rectangle = sf::RectangleShape(sf::Vector2f(120, 50));
    rectangle.setFillColor(sf::Color(0,0,0));
    mainWindow.create(sf::VideoMode(1024, 768, 32), "Test");

    sf::View view(sf::FloatRect(0,0,1000,600));
    mainWindow.setView(view);

    leftMousePressed, rightMousePressed, isExiting = false;

    sf::Event currentEvent;
    mainWindow.clear(white);
    mainWindow.draw(paper.getSprite());
    mainWindow.display();

    while (!isExiting)
    {
        while (mainWindow.pollEvent(currentEvent))
        {
            switch (currentEvent.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::MouseMoved:
            {
                if (rightMousePressed == true)
                {
                    std::cout << "Mouse Panned\n";
                }
                if (leftMousePressed == true)
                {
                    std::cout << "Mouse is Drawing\n";
                }
                break;
            }
            case sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed:
            {
                std::cout << "Mouse Pressed\n";

                mouseX = currentEvent.mouseButton.x;
                mouseY = currentEvent.mouseButton.y;

                if (currentEvent.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)
                {
                    leftMousePressed = true;
                }
                else if (currentEvent.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Right)
                {
                    rightMousePressed = true;
                }
                break;
            }
            case sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased:
            {
                std::cout << "Mouse Released\n";
                if (currentEvent.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)
                {
                    leftMousePressed = false;
                }
                else if(currentEvent.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Right)
                {
                    rightMousePressed = false;
                }
                break;
            }
            case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
            {
                if (currentEvent.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
                {
                    close();
                }
                //No right movement yet, was testing.
                else if (currentEvent.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Left)
                {
                    moveCamera(currentEvent);
                }
                break;
            }
            case sf::Event::Closed:
            {
                close();
                break;
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
void MainWindow::moveCamera(sf::Event key)
{
    std::cout << "Inside moveCamera\n";
    //No right movement yet, was testing.
    //Movement is also hardcoded for testing as well.
    view.move(100, 0);
    mainWindow.setView(view);
    mainWindow.clear(white);
    mainWindow.draw(paper.getSprite());
    mainWindow.display();
    std::cout << "Leaving moveCamera\n";
}
void draw()
{
    //mainWindow.draw();
}
void MainWindow::close()
{
    std::cout << "Closing...\n";
    mainWindow.close();
    isExiting = true;
}
```

Comment: You could add same texture end of the first one when needed.

Comment: @sunofkyuss Well, that's the problem.  I have no way, that I know of, to detect once I'm outside the view of the texture programmatically.  If there is a way, that would be great.

Comment: @MORTAL Setting the view area that large will just zoom it out.  That's the way views work.  I did as you suggested and the texture was a tiny little square, not repeating at all.  That's why I had a textureRect.  Without setting a textureRect the sprite doesn't know how far/how much to repeat.